# React does not set state immediately

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning reactjs.
I am trying to set the state with an object received from the API, and then display the results from the state. When I try to display the results, it shows state object undefined. When I  query the API for a second time, it sets the state to the object received from API.

```
const SearchByName = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({
    recipesObj: {},
    loding: false,
  });


  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setRecipes({ loading: true });

      const res = await axios.get(`url_to_API`);

      console.log(res.data) // prints returned object from API

      setRecipes({ recipesObj: res.data, loading: false });

      console.log(recipes.recipesObj); // empty object

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
};

 const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
    setSearchStr('');
  };
```

Comment: If you're fetching data from an API you should put the function in a ```useEffect()``` hook. Also API calls are asynchronous by nature so state will be updated once the request is successful.

Comment: You've made a typo (on loding/loading )

Comment: `it shows state object undefined` -> is it `recipes` undefined or `recipes.recipesObj ` is undefined?

Comment: Undefined was solved by Naren’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the state with `{ loading: true }`, here `recipes.recipesObj` will become undefined. you need to prepend the earlier state. Try changing like this or you can use different `state` to manage the `loading and data`

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setRecipes({ ...recipes, loading: true }); // Here was the problem
      or setRecipes({ recipesObj: {}, loading: true });

      const res = await axios.get(`url_to_API`);

      console.log(res.data) // prints returned object from API

      setRecipes({ recipesObj: res.data, loading: false });

      console.log(recipes.recipesObj);

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In react we have lifecycle components your code is correct but what missing is useEffect for functional components

```
  import {useEffect, useState } from "react"

 const SearchByName = () => {
     const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState({
        recipesObj: {},
        loding: false,
  });

 useEffect(()=>{
       // useEffect can access fetchData anytime
      fetchData()
 },[])

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setRecipes({ loading: true });

      const res = await axios.get(`url_to_API`);

      console.log(res.data) // prints returned object from API

      setRecipes({ recipesObj: res.data, loading: false });

      console.log(recipes.recipesObj);

    } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
    }
  };
};
```

It should work now, the only difference is the useEffect lifecycle hook

Comment: Leaving `fetchData()` function in `useEffect()` did not do anything . I left `fetchData()` in `onSubmit()` function and added a callback recipes in a `useEffect()`. Now, it produces my desired result. Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. `const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
  };
  useEffect(() => {}, [recipes]);`

Comment: that will also work, since you passed in recipes, so react will watch for a change in recipe

Answer (score 0):

Remember set state in react is and Async function

To know more about what is state in react please check this [Llink in react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) .

React state in both functional and class based is an async function, to handle what you want you should check your state in an useEffect or outside of that related function that setState fired.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [dataFetched,setDataFetched] = React.useState(false);
  const mockTheRequest = () => {
    // make the request and set the state
    setDataFetched(true)
  }
    
   React.useEffect(()=>{
      // fire your xhr request when component rendered.
      mockTheRequest()
    },[])
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(dataFetched){
      // on data fetched
      console.log("state", dataFetched)
    }
  },[dataFetched])
  
  return(
    <div>
      <span>
        is data fetched? {dataFetched}
      </span>
    </div> 
  )
}
```